# Selector on press not working in imageVIew

Tags: android

I am using selector for imageView to change image on press event.
but it is not changing image when I press on it.

Here is selector,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item 
   android:state_pressed="true" 
   android:drawable="@drawable/fed_1" />
 <item 
   android:drawable="@drawable/fed" />
</selector>
```

And this is my imageview,

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
android:src="@drawable/sel_fed" />
```

Also tried using background for image view but it's not working.

Comment: Set `android:clickable="true"` for imageview in XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add `android:clickable="true"`. Your imageView will be like this

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:src="@drawable/sel_fed" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `src` to `background` and add `android:clickable="true"` to your `ImageView`

Comment: thanks.. android:clickable="true" did work. 
works on src and background both.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fed_1" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fed_1" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fed"></item>

</selector>
```

Change src to background in your image view.

```
  android:background="@drawable/sel_fed"
```

Comment: tried this too. but not working, and also tried to use background insted if src.

Comment: Have you tried chaning scr to background in ImageView, It should work.